# How to merge to HashSets into one with limitations using java 8 streaming?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, hashset

I have 2 classes:

```
class A
{
 int x;
 String y;
}

class B
{
 int x;
}
```

My 2 hashSets are from type A and I want to merge them into one `hashSet` from type B when mapping `A.x to B.x`

The way I thought is to iterate them both, create new object and just copy the value of A.x. Was wondering if there is a pretty and more elegant way to do it using java 8 streaming?

Thanks a lot

Comment: So you have a set of A and a set of B and you want one set containing both A's and B's, but if "x" is the same, then there is a duplicate - regardless of if it's an A or a B?

Comment: yes, if it's duplicated it's ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
HashSet<B> hb = Stream.concat(ha1.stream(), ha2.stream())
    .map(a -> new B(a.x))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

Here is how this works:

- [`Stream.concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) concatenates the items from the first and second `HashSet<A>`s
- [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) produces instances of `B` from instances of `A`
- [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) produces the final `HashSet<B>` from the stream.

Note that this implies that `B`'s `hashCode` and `equal` are properly implemented, which is what you must do in order to use `B` with `HashSet<B>` anyway.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/QJ012x)

Comment: ...nailed also! You were faster than me!